# Why does the server run both of these handlers in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have my node app set like this- I've got two handlers, one for requests to the root URL and the other for the slug, and when I go to the root, it does load up, then crashes. When I go to the slug URL, same thing.
This error shows up:

```
url is pointing to root
url has a slug
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
```

What did I do wrong?

```
app.get(
    '/:slug',
    (req, res) => {
        connection.query(`select * from blogs where slug="${slug}"`,
            (error, results) => {
                if (error) console.log(error);
                console.log('url has a slug');
                res.render(
                    'somepage',
                     results
                )
            }
        )

    }
)

app.get(
    '/',
    (req, res) => {
        connection.query(`select * from blogs`,
            (error, results) => {
                if (error) console.log(error);
                console.log('url is pointing to root');
                res.render(
                    'index',
                    {
                        title: 'Home page',
                        blogs: results
                    }
                )
            }
        )

    }
)
```

Comment: `slug` is just a _query parameter_ on the root so that's the reason why both routes are firing.

Comment: @Andy um.. I was following a web tutorial, where can I read more about it?

Comment: Assuming that's Express [here's the documentation on routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). What you could do is something like `/blog/:slug` and then that route would only fire when you fetch from `/blog`, and the root one wouldn't fire at all.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the link- I am reading up on that in a new tab. :)

Comment: Note that the order of the routes is important. The reason `/` is last is so that it can fire when no other previous routes are picked up.

Comment: @Andy So I read the documentation and searched a bit, and it seems using '/blog/:slug' is a good idea but I am wondering if there is some way I could do '/:slug'. Doing it this way would probably be better for google SEO. 
I understand it could take some time to explain, so if you know some resource off the top of your head, please let me know.
Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: No, you can't do that. `/` is the route. `slug` is just a query parameter. So Express will call both of those routes because they _both_ handle the root. Adding a new element to the path is the only way to differentiate between them.

Comment: @Andy Actually you are wrong. Express does support what he is trying to do

Comment: @slebetman then why is Express running both routes?

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for the error you observe:

After loading the home page with `GET /`, browsers make an additional `GET /favicon.ico` request to retrieve the icon that decorates the browser tab (which is [image] on StackOverflow). That additional request would be served by your "slug route", with `req.params.slug = "favicon.ico"`. I expect the variable `slug` in your code to be undefined. Anyway, the `select` statement will probably fail during this additional request.