# Is there a reason res.json is crashing my server?

Tags: express, syntax

I've verified that res.json with anything passed as an argument in my code crashes my application. If I omit it, it doesn't crash until I deploy it when I get a code that says it was terminated without a response.

```
const express = require('express');
const OpenseaScraper = require('opensea-scraper')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const NFT = require('./NFTModel')
const PORT = 8001
const server = express()
require('dotenv').config()

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, () => console.log('This application has been connected to the Mogo DB!'))

server.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let NFTs = []
        const ranking = await OpenseaScraper.rankings()
        
        ranking.forEach(async item => {
            const slug = item.slug
            const name = item.name
            const logoUrl = item.logo
            NFTs.push({slug, name, logoUrl})
            NFT.findOne({ "slug": slug }, (err, value) => {
                if (err) { console.error(err) }
                if (!value) {
                    let newNFT = new NFT({slug, name, logoUrl})
                    newNFT.save() }
            })
        })
    
        res.json('NFTs')
        NFTs = []

    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error 404')
    }
})

server.get('/:slug', async (req, res) => {
    const basicInfo = await OpenseaScraper.basicInfo(req.params.slug)
    const floorPrice = basicInfo.floorPrice
    res.json({name: req.params.slug.replaceAll('-', ' '), 'floor price': floorPrice})
    await NFT.findOneAndUpdate({ "slug": req.params.slug }, {$set: {"floorPrice": floorPrice}})
})

const app = server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  const port = app.address().port;
  console.log(`Express is working on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is the top of the error, as the error is really really long. It has a variable at the bottom of the error that says isAxiosError: true. Which makes no sense because axios isn't even a dependency here.

```
D:\NFT\NFTscraper2.0\node_modules\opensea-scraper\node_modules\axios\lib\core\cr
eateError.js:16
  var error = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (D:\NFT\NFTscraper2.0\node_modules\opensea-scraper\node_modul
es\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (D:\NFT\NFTscraper2.0\node_modules\opensea-scraper\node_modules\ax
ios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\NFT\NFTscraper2.0\node_modules\opense
a-scraper\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:269:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  config: {
    url: 'https://api.opensea.io/collection/favicon.ico',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4'
    },
```

This is the Heroku crash if I remove res.json

```
2022-06-11T06:18:55.206286+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
2022-06-11T06:18:55.206934+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=open-sea-awesome-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=28c20752-9292-4353-9ac6-43d21c3b6790 fwd="216.198.98.78" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2430ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-06-11T06:19:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/676cfa9a-fcf9-4a34-b212-2543ded2288e/activity/builds/4f50f993-dc2e-4dbd-bdc0-299ca24c6016
2022-06-11T06:19:37.607293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H21 desc="Backend connection refused" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=open-sea-awesome-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=d93cf7f3-0921-4d08-a5b2-f31a5e8fa49a fwd="216.198.98.78" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-11T06:25:15.979471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-06-11T06:25:19.602275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-06-11T06:25:19.811341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Comment: If a Node.js app crashes, it gives a reason.

Comment: According to the error trace, the crash is because of the 404 Not Found response to the `GET https://api.opensea.io/collection/favicon.ico` request.  I assume one of your `await OpenseaScraper...` statements makes this request, but is not prepared to handle 404 responses.  Wrap these statements in `try {...} catch(err) {...}`. It has got nothing to do with `res.json`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen that didn't work still got the same error

Comment: Please update your question with the code changes you made.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen done

Comment: You haven't wrapped the `OpenseaScraper.basicInfo(...)`. Also the catch block must finish the response, for example, `catch(err) {res.status(400).end()}`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my comment: Browsers typically request `/favicon.ico` from any server (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72077103/16462950), and this request would be handled by your `server.get('/:slug', ...)` route, effectively calling

```js
await OpenseaScraper.basicInfo("favicon.ico");
```

Since this probably cannot work, you should have a special route before `server.get('/:slug', ...)` to handle this favicon request:

```js
server.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => {
  res.end();
});
server.get('/:slug', ...);
```