# How to prevent express from executing subsequent routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I've been learning express routing and built a test server to test some express routes while also learning express-handlebars.

I have the following Routes in my Application:

```
    app.get("/products/search", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("Request received");
    res.render("productshome", {layout: "productsprimary"}); 
    });

    app.use((req, res)=>{
    console.log("This page does not exist");
    res.render("producterror", {layout: "productsprimary"}); 

    });

    app.listen(port, ()=>{
      console.log("Server Started"); 
    });
```

When my Server gets a get request for /products/search URL, the required handlebars (.hbs) file is sent to the Browser. However, my next Route i.e. app.use() gets executed as well. I don't get any errors but the flow of control goes to this Route. How do I stop this request from going to the app.use(). I'm using this Route for unrecognized URLs like /products/dsdfsdfsdfdsd and so on. Please could somebody advise what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you have them in the order you've shown above? If the `app.use` is **after** the `app.get`, I wouldn't expect it to get executed if the URL matches the `app.get` route. (I **would** if the call to `app.use` were *before* the call to `app.get`; that's the nature of middleware.)

Comment: Could it be there's an error occurring during the `app.get` callback?

Comment: hey @T.J. Yes I double checked and that's exactly how I have the routes setup. So I've got, app.get(), app.post() and app.use(). The flow of control still goes to the app.use() even after I've called res.render() in my app.get().

Comment: Nope, not showing any errors in the Terminal/Browser's Console

Comment: I've just put the code above into a project with express-handlebars. When the route matches, the `app.use` callback is **not** executed (and is executed when the route doesn't match). So whatever is going on is going on because of something not in the question.

Comment: Thanks T.J. I dunno if I'm missing something. I'm going try making another Server and see if I'm getting the same issue. I do have some logic setup in my app.get() and app.get() routes but it's weird that I'm not getting any errors. Nevertheless I'm gonna try isolating this in another file and see if that helps. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that it is the same request that goes to both `app.get` and `app.use`? I ask because browsers often send a request `GET /favicon.ico` after having loaded a page (in order to retrieve an "icon" for the tab). And this _second_ request would be handled by `app.use`, which is valid for _any_ path. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/72077103/16462950)

Comment: @HeikoTheißen - That is a ***very*** good point.

Comment: Hey @Heiko that's an excellent point and that's exactly what I thought and looked for that additional request though I can't see that 'favicon' request on my Chrome Browser. I sometimes do get that error in the Console but for this Project it's not showing up.

Comment: Instead of `GET /favicon.ico`, it can also be _any_ subsequent request that loads an image, a stylesheet or a script for the `productshome` page.

Comment: So I tested the Same code without any changes with the Safari Browser and I didn't get that error. So I guess it looks like Chrome was sending some subsequent requests to my Server. I guess it's that infamous favicon.ico lol

Answer (score 0):

When you access a webpage for the first time (or when you start a new session), modern web browsers automatically send a GET request for favicon.

In your code, as the second middleware, you use an Application level middleware, where there's no mount path (so root is used). This middleware is executed for each client request if there's no handler function prior to it.  In your case, "products/search" is handled by the first middleware. But then for the second request (favicon), Express skips the first middleware(because the mount path doesn't match) and executes the second middleware(as there's no mount path in it).

However this doesn't harm your app so you can just ignore it. If you want to get rid of this behaviour, use Express's serve-favicon module to send a favicon.ico to the client.

```
import express from 'express'
import favicon from 'serve-favicon'
const app = express()
app.get("/products/search", (req, res)=>{
console.log("Request received");
res.render("productshome", {layout: "productsprimary"}); 
});

//Midldleware to handle favicon request
app.use(favicon('favicon.ico')) //add a favicon.ico to the current path

app.use((req, res)=>{
console.log("This page does not exist");
res.render("producterror", {layout: "productsprimary"}); 

});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log("Server Started"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks you're right. I tested my Application using Firefox and Safari and I didn't run into that issue. Chrome was sending the favicon request causing the catch-all route to execute. Thanks for the favicon middleware.