# When in the browser I typed 'localhost:3005', it works a long time, before display first result

Tags: node.js, http

I wrote simple server running script on node.js

```
const http = require('http')

let requestsCount = 0
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    requestsCount++
    response.write(`Leo Garsia ${requestsCount}`)

})

server.listen(3005, () => {
    console.info('Server is Running on port 3005')
})
```

When in the browser I typed 'localhost:3005',  it works a long time, before display first result. (about 10 minutes)
Why does it huppens?

And then when I refresh browser it  requestsCount increments twice. And displays the result like 2,4,6, and so on.
Very interesting why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When in the browser I typed 'localhost:3005', it works a long time, before display first result. (about 10 minutes)

Your response never finishes, because your code lacks the `response.end()` statement after the `response.write`. Therefore the browser waits until timeout (10 minutes) and then displays what it has received so far.

> And then when I refresh browser it requestsCount increments twice. And displays the result like 2,4,6, and so on. Very interesting why?

I suspect the other request is the one the browser makes for the favorites icon, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72077103/16462950).

Answer (score 0):

as Heiko TheiBen said, I mess response.end()
I have replaced the code with using the 'express'.
Now when I type "localhost:3005/leo", the result appears immediately.

```
const express = require('express')

const app=express();
let requestsCount = 0
app.listen(3005, () =>{
   console.log('Server is running on port 3005...')
})

app.get('/leo', (request, response)=>{
    requestsCount++
    response.write(`Request URL is, ${request.url}  count is, ${requestsCount}`)
    response.end()
    console.info(`Request URL is, ${request.url}  count is, ${requestsCount}`)
})
```